# What is the difference between `__del__` and `__delete__`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructor, destruction

Suppose someone didn't know what the difference was between `__del__` and `__delete__`? Write an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

#### [`object.__del__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> Called when the instance is about to be destroyed. This is also called a finalizer or (improperly) a destructor. If a base class has a `__del__()` method, the derived class’s `__del__()` method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper deletion of the base class part of the instance.

I think this means that `my_object.__del__` will get called by CPython's garbage collector after the reference count for `my_object` drops to zero.

#### [`object.__delete__(self, instance)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delete__):

> Called to delete the attribute on an instance `instance` of the owner class.

The `__delete__` dunder method is related to python's notion of [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor); a descriptor is "any object which defines the methods `__get__()`, `__set__()`, or `__delete__()`." Descriptors can be used to implement custom behavior for attribute lookup/assignment/deletion (via `__get__`/`__set__`/`__delete__`, respectively).

#### See also:

- [The `del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#del): "Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace... Deletion of attribute references, subscriptions and slicings is passed to the primary object involved..."
- The [`delattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#delattr) built-in function. From the docs, "The function deletes the named attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, `delattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `del x.foobar`."
- [`object.__delattr__(self, name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delattr__) is called when attribute deletion is attempted. According to the docs, "This should only be implemented if `del obj.name` is meaningful for the object." Thus, defining a user class with the method `MyClass.__delattr__` enables custom behavior when e.g. the statement `del my_object.an_attr` is invoked, or (equivalently) when `delattr(my_object, 'an_attr')` is called.
- [`object.__delitem__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) is "Called to implement deletion of `self[key]`." Thus, defining a user class with the method `MyClass.__delitem__` enables custom behavior when e.g. the statement `del my_object[a_key]` is invoked.

Answer (score -2):

`__del__` is called when you delete an object and `__delete__` is sometimes called when you delete an attribute of an object.

```
del x.my_num    # __delete__
del x           # __del__
```

#### ABOUT `__del__:`

The following code shows when `__del__` gets called:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        file = open("really_cool_file.txt", "w+")
        self._f = file

    def __del__(self):
        print("closing any open files ")
        self._f.close()

my_instance = MyClass()
del my_instance
```

***If*** `my_instance` is the last label pointing to the data, then `del my_instance` calls `MyClass.__del__(my_instance)`

Technically, `del my_instance` only deletes the label `my_instance`. Imagine people at a party all wearing names tags. Sometimes a person has 6 or 7 names tags on simultaneously, and other times, they only have one. Python will kick anyone out of the party who is not wearing at least one name tag. `MyClass.__del__(my_instance)` gets called when the last name-tag/label is removed from a piece of data.

The code above shows an example of when we make sure to close an open file. Another example might be to count of the number active instances of a given class:

```
class Klass:
    count = 0
    # `count` belongs to the class
    # instances do not each get their own copy of `count`
    def __init__(self):
        type(self).count += 1
        self.instance_var = "I belong to instances"
    def __del__(self):
        type(self).count -= 1
obj = Klass()
print(obj.count)
```

#### ABOUT `__delete__`

Unlike `__del__`, `__delete__` has to do with descriptors.
The code below describes the behavior of `obj.my_var` or `getattr(obj, “my_var”)`

class Klaus:
    def **getattribute**(self, attrname):
        try:
            attribute = attrname from instance Klaus
        except AttributeError:
            attribute = attrname from class Klaus

```
    # Begin code for handling "descriptors"
    if hasattr(attribute, '__get__'):
        attr = attribute.__get__(self, Klaus)
    # End code for handling "descriptors"

    return attribute
```

If `my_var` is a descriptor, then following two lines of code equivalent:

```
x = obj.my_var
x = Klass.my_var.__get__(obj, "my_var")
```

Just as `__getattribute__` checks whether the attribute has a `__get__` method or not, `__delattr__` will check whether the attribute has a `__delete__` method or not.

```
def __delattr__(self, name):
    attribute = getattr(self, name)
    if hasattr(attribute, "__delete__"):
       attribute.__delete__(self)
    else:
       del self.__dict__[name]
```

You can see when `__delete__` gets called by viewing the following code:

```
class desc:
    def __delete__(descriptor, instance_of_Klaus):
        print("attribute was deleted")

class Klaus:
    d = desc()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

my_instance = Klaus()
del my_instance.d
```

When dealing with descriptors, the following lines of code are all equivalent:

```
del my_instance.d
delattr(my_instance, "d")
Klaus.d.__delete__(my_instance)
```

Comment: `del` is not called when you do `del something`. It is called when an object's reference count reaches zero (or more generally, when reference the object gets garbage collected). This is actually a source of incompatibility between different python implementations

Comment: So, note, `del` doesn't delete objects, it deletes *names*. Python gives you no explicit control over the allocation / deallocation of objects. I think this is a good question and this could be a good answer, but it gets a fundamental part wrong and thus is misleading. IOW: "`del my_instance` is the same as `MyClass.__del__(my_instance)`" is **absolutely** wrong.